# Must proofs always be cited (Thesis)?

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing

I have some proofs of theorems in my thesis that are very similar to the proofs from the literature ( "my" proofs are more extended and have more explaination, the structure isn't the same either). Those are really complicated proofs so I can't do them by myself with an entirely different approach. Need I to cite the source and say that the proof is basically the same just more detailed? Is is plagiarism if I don't cite it?

Comment: PhD's thesis? Then you better reference *everything*. If it is some undergraduate thesis then I don't think anyone will be too worried about plagiarism, *unless* you specifically write these are original proofs of yours.

Comment: it's for Bachelor thesis.

Comment: @NotNow Then don't worry too much, yet I think it'd be much better for you to give references for everything.

Comment: It costs you nothing to cite the other proof, and you might impress someone with your scholarship, so why not do it?

Answer (score 4):

Yes. You need to cite them. You are using someone else's idea, and you need to give them credit for it. Anything else is plagiarism.

Comment: It it enough to write "compare with [source]" or must it be a direct citation. I have seen in most literature the citations for a maths thesis are indirect.

Comment: I have used "the following proof is adapted from [x]" in my papers before for similar situations.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in Johanna's answer, it is always best to give relevant citations. I would also encourage you to talk with your advisor. He would be the one to know what's best.

Comment: I am worried that I will get too many citations if I add citations for the proofs.

Comment: @NotNow: That's why- ask your adviser. He will know how many citations are the norm, or how well some proofs are established. Note that we do not cite a proof of Pythagora's theorem, as it's a well known theorem. Your adviser would know what to cite, and what not to. Also, I do not personally think there's such a thing as "over citing". If you used someones work or ideas, you should give them credit. To do otherwise is unethical, and perhaps plagiarism.